# How to use furniture in this sentence?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, modifiers

Is it correct to say:

> The only **furniture**  that I have is a bed

Or I have to put some sort of modifier before it? For example:

> The only **piece of furniture** that I have is a bed.

Comment: Yup, for uncountables, like *information* or *luggage*, you have to use a modifier like *a piece of*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter option is correct.

> The only **piece of furniture** that I have is a bed.

Your former sentence is not wrong in some situations,though.

> The only **bed** that I have is white

I will be honest, I speak English as my first language, and this kind of thing is confusing even to me.
In my experience, if it is a defined group, rather than specific object, like furniture, rather than a bed, then it's not preceded by "a piece of".
 it also depends on how it is used. If it is used singularly, like "a" piece, then it includes "piece of". If is not one piece of furniture, like:

> I **have furniture** in my house

then it does not need "piece of" preceding furniture
Any questions?

Comment: It's confusing that *furniture* is an uncountable, because most of the time it's really easy to count. It really doesn't *need* to be uncountable, unlike *sugar* for example. But other than that, it behaves normally for an uncountable.

Comment: yes, actually. i did not know the term for that.